# haskell - Couldn't match type ‘(Char, Int)’ with ‘[Char]’ error

Tags: haskell, syntax, syntax-error, type-mismatch, function-call

I am writing a function to expand a String

Example:

```
foo "a4b4"
```

should give back:

```
"aaaabbbb"
```

Here is my code:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo (x:xs) = let curent = fooHelp(x, read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
             in x : (curent) ++ foo (tail xs)
```

fooHelp:

```
fooHelp :: String -> Int -> String
fooHelp x n 
             | n >= 3 = x ++ fooHelp x (n - 1) 
             | n == 2 = x
             | n == 1 = ""
```

and charToString:

```
charToString :: Char -> String
charToString c = [c]
```

it takes x and appends it to the current. In current fooHelp will give back expanded String

example : `foo "a4b4"` then `x = "a"`, `xs = "4b4"`, `xs !! 0 = '4'`
`read $ charToString( xs !! 0 ) :: Int)` will convert char `'4'` to int `4` and pass it to fooHelp alongside with x("a") -> `fooHelp(x, 4)` and give back "aaa". Then `x : current` should give back `"aaaa"`because `x = "a"` and current `"aaa"` and then recursive call with `++ foo tail xs` where `xs ="b4"`  and it should repeat the process.

I am getting the error:

```
test.hs:173:34: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘(Char, Int)’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: (Char, Int)
    • In the first argument of ‘fooHelp’, namely
        ‘(x, read $ charToString (xs !! 0) :: Int)’
      In the expression:
        fooHelp (x, read $ charToString (xs !! 0) :: Int)
      In an equation for ‘curent’:
          curent = fooHelp (x, read $ charToString (xs !! 0) :: Int)
    |
173 | foo (x:xs) = let curent = fooHelp(x, read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where did I make mistake? I tested function fooHelp and it works fine with such arguments as in foo.

Testing fooHelp:

```
xs = "4b4"

test =  read $ charToString( xs !!0 ) :: Int

*Main> test
4
```

Comment: you "tested function fooHelp and it works fine"? if you'd *actually tested calling the function* instead of trying out it parts, you'd see the problem right away, by yourself. for quick-n-dirty testing, you can enter your function definitions in GHCi multi-line mode, between the `:{` and `:}` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classic mistake is to call a function like `f (x1, x2)`. In Haskell functions have *one* parameter, and often this is *not* a tuple.

Your `fooHelper` function has type:

```
fooHelp :: String -> (Int -> String)
```

so it is a function that takes a `String`, and the returns a function that maps `Int`s on `String`s. You thus should call the function like:

```
(fooHelp x) (read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
```

or less verbose:

```
(fooHelp x) (read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
```

But now the types still not match: `x` is a `Char`, not a `String`, you can wrap it in a list, like:

```
fooHelp [x] (read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
```

like:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo (x:xs) = let curent = fooHelp [x] (read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
             in x : (curent) ++ foo (tail xs)
```

But still this function has a problem: we iterate over the string, so eventually we will reach an empty string, and `foo` has no case for that. We need to return the empty string in that case, like:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo (x:xs) = let curent = fooHelp [x] (read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
             in x : (curent) ++ foo (tail xs)
foo [] = ""
```

But it is still not very elegant. We here perform a lot of unnecessary operations, like wrapping characters to strings, etc.

We can make use of the [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) function to repeat a character a given number of times. For example:

```
Prelude> replicate 3 'a'
"aaa"
```

Furthermore the [**`digitToInt :: Char -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) function can parse a digit character to the corresponding `Int`:

```
Prelude Data.Char> digitToInt '3'
3
```

So we here can use these two to each time take the first two characters of the string, and use `replicate (digitToInt k) x` to generate a string where `x` si repeated the requested amount of time, and perform recursion on the rest of the string, like:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

foo :: String -> String
foo (x:k:xs) = replicate (digitToInt k) x ++ foo xs
foo _ = ""
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `fooHelp(x, read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)` tries to pass a single argument — a `(Char, Int)` pair — to `fooHelp`, which is wrong.  Presumably, you want to instead write:

```
fooHelp (charToString x) (read $ charToString( xs !! 0  ) :: Int)
```